# Matching Uppercased Character with Lower Cased Character, Java

Tags: java, android, string

**How to match Upper Cased Characters with Lower Cased Characters without using ToUpper/ToLower, is that possible?**

Example:

```
String content = "are";
String keyword = "ARE";
if(content==keyword ){
    System.out.println("Working!");
}else{
    System.out.println("Not Working!");
}
```

The code above will print `Not Working!`.

Example 2:

```
String content = "how are you?";
String keyword = "ARE";
if(content.matches("(.*)(\\b)"+keyword+"(\\b)(.*)"))){
    System.out.println("Working!");
}else{
    System.out.println("Not Working!");
}
```

Comment: `content.equalsIgnoreCase(keyword)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule 1: Use `string1.equals(string2)` instead of `string1 == string2` to compare strings.

You'll find `.equalsIgnoreCase(...)` for your purpose.